# Test Driven Deployment in laravel

Tags: laravel, server

I write this code for delete record test case but it gives me error. Please check below code

```
public function a_user_can_delete_the_task(){
    $data = [
        'title' => 'abc',
        'description' => 'xyz'
    ];
    $post = Post::create($data);
    //When the user hit's the endpoint to update the task
    $response = $this->delete('/api/v1/delete/'.$post->id, $post->toArray());
    $response->dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code it will work

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_delete_the_task(){
    $data = [
        'title' => 'abc',
        'description' => 'xyz'
    ];
    $post = Post::create($data);
    //When the user hit's the endpoint to update the task
    $response = $this->delete('/api/v1/delete/'.$post->id, $post->toArray());
    //The task should be updated in the database.
    $this->assertDatabaseMissing('posts',['id'=> $post->id]);
}
```